# Function attribute used in recursion - does a global function attribute exist?

Tags: python

I have a function:

```
def fib(n, fib_d = {}):
     
   if n < 2:
      return 1
    
   if n not in fib_d:
     fib_d[n] = fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
    
 
   return fib_d[n]

fib(1000)
# a big number returned in an instance
```

Then I try to create `fib_d` as an attribute of a function which data I could access:

```
def fib(n):
   fib.fib_d = {}
   
   if n < 2:
      return 1
    
   if n not in fib.fib_d:
     fib.fib_d[n] = fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
    
 
   return fib.fib_d[n]
fib(10)
# returns 89 in an instance
fib(100)
# runs till I stop it
```

So I am guessing that `fib_d` is being created each time as an empty parameter, hence the slow calculation

I am wondering if I can have a `global` function attribute so that I could access it's content like:

```
fib.fib_d
# {2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 8, 6: 13, 7: 21, 8: 34, 9: 55, 10: 89, ..., n: m}
```

I tried:

```
def fib(n, fib.fib_d):
   ...
```

But that's not valid, I understand that probably functions attribute should be bound only to that function but I am curious if there is such thing as global function attributes or at least attribute that can be used in a recursion.

Comment: This is just trying to implement caching manually, which is already done by [`cache`/`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html). Strictly you don't need an explicit cache `fib_d` to be visible to your code, you only need to make sure the bytecode can access it.

Comment: This is a duplicate; there are [726 hits for *\[python\] implement function cache*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+implement+function+cache)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use a cache, or lru_cache.

But to do it like you've asked for, the easiest way to do this is to define your function within a closure:

```
def make_fib():

   def fib(n):
   
       if n < 2:
          return 1
    
       if n not in fib.fib_d:
         fib.fib_d[n] = fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
       return fib.fib_d[n]
   fib.fib_d = {}
   return fib

f= make_fib()
f(2000)
```

That way, we have an attribute of the function properly scoped.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you just want to cache the results for each func

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def fib(n):
   if n < 2:
      return 1
   return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

Comment: I am aware of this library, thank you, but it does not answer my question if there is a such thing as global function attributes.

Comment: I think it could be a global function, since function is first class object

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the function already has an attribute `fib_d`:

```py
def fib(n):
   if n < 2:
       return 1
   
   if not hasattr(fib, "fib_d"):
      fib.fib_d = {}
    
   if n not in fib.fib_d:
       fib.fib_d[n] = fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
   
   return fib_d[n]

fib(1000)
```

Comment: Okay, that works out, thank you. Any way I can use it in a function and not rewrite it's value during recursion?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis Isn't that what this code does ? How does this overwrite anything ?

Comment: It works as expected, I am just wondering if there is a way to make this work with moving `fib.fib_d = {}` inside of the function, sort like `global` variable would work.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis yes, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getattr` to fetch the attribute if it already exists or create it otherwise:

```
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    fib.cache = getattr(fib, 'cache', {})
    if n not in fib.cache:
        fib.cache[n] = fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
    return fib.cache[n]
```

This is essentially just altering your unconditional creation of `fib_d` to only happen if it doesn't already exist; it's self-contained within the function and doesn't need an external definition or closure for the attribute.